# Why those li tags ain't included in <ul> tag in inspector? URL: https://github.com/Lavitaebella37/Github.git

Tags: html

As you can see from the image below the four Icons which are made by `li` tag should be included in `ul` tag, but it shows that it doesn't involve them. Is there any structural error?

[image]

```
<section class="section section--feature">
            <div class="summary">
                <h2 class="summary__title">Welcome home, developers</h2>
                <p class="summary__description">GitHub fosters a fast, flexible, and collaborative development process
                    that lets you work on your own or with others.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="video">
                <div class="video-ratio">
                    <iframe width="704" height="396" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/afvT1c1ii0c"
                    title="YouTube video player"
                    frameborder="0"
                    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tiles">
                <div class="inner">
                    <ul class="clearfix">
                        <li>
                            <img src="img/feature-tile__build.png" alt="build">
                            <h3>For everything you build</h3>
                            <p>Host and manage your code on GitHub. You can keep your work private or share it with the
                                world.</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="img/feature-tile__work.png" alt="work">
                            <h3>A better way to work</h3>
                            <p>From hobbyists to professionals, GitHub helps developers simplify the way they build
                                software.</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="img/feature-tile__projects.png" alt="projects">
                            <h3>Millions of projects</h3>
                            <p>GitHub is home to millions of open source projects. Try one out or get inspired to create
                                your own.</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="img/feature-tile__platform.png" alt="platform">
                            <h3>One platform, from start to finish</h3>
                            <p>With hundreds of integrations, GitHub is flexible enough to be at the center of your
                                development process.</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Can you include some code and not an inspect img link.

Comment: oh my bad, I just edited it.

Comment: from what i can see the img are included if they are not printing to your screen then make sure that the path is corect. And that the img is called correctly for example.                                                                             
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" alt="Mountain">                     this link starts with "https// or if needed use <?echo?> or /.. if img is located one file up.

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**.

Comment: but what I mean is that the four li tags which consist of img tag, h3 tag and p tag are supposed to be in the parent tag which is ul tag further named tiles class, but as you can see from the image, the tiles class is empty. Those li tags are out of the tiles tag.